# Aborting a jenkins job doesn't stop selenium script running in background

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

When ever I abort a jenkins job chromedriver.exe doesn't stop, it will continue to finish the full selenium script. I have to stop the process manually.

How can I overcome this, when I abort jenkins job it should also stop chromedriver.exe which is running in headless mode.

Comment: Is the Jenkins job running multiple scripts or just one? It seems reasonable that it would finish the script that was already running but I don't know much about Jenkins

Comment: Jenkins will teminate chromedriver.exe with delay. Don't force close Chrome browser. If you do it, script cannot be stopped properly.

Comment: @Yun chromedriver.exe is not terminating until the full script is executed

Answer (score 0):

As I know , if a build is aborted, there's no way to execute any build steps (or post build steps) in it any more . So what you can do s add a method in your precondition of your script to close existing chromedriver.exe before initiating a new session , so only one chrome driver is remains .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}       
        System.out.println("chromw driver is  Killed");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use task manager (right click taskbar > task manager) to kill the process. Shouldn't give any grief after that! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question asks for a way to terminate the process without manual intervention; it appears that you were a bit confused with the question. `:)`